# Close Google Chrome on Mac OS X through Java

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome

I am trying to close Google Chrome from a java application by running the following command

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall Google Chrome");
```

It does not work, I can close Firefox and Safari using the same command.. but Chrome wont close. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does that command work from the Terminal?

Comment: Yes killall Google\ Chrome or killall 'Google Chrome' works through terminal. I did try Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall \"Google Chrome\""); and Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall Google\\ Chrome"); but both these commands dint work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working with the following command :

```
String cmds[] = {"killall","Google Chrome"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```